# Програмно нажать на кнопку JS / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Есть кнопка, на которую нужно нажать програмно: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но такие методы:

```
$(".btn btn-warning").click();
```

или

```
$(".btn btn-warning").submit();
```

не работают. В консоли Chrome пишет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в других случаях (? *вроде* ?) это работало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они оба (`btn` и `btn-warning`) - классы одного элемента:

```
$(".btn.btn-warning").click();
```

---

P.S. В других случаях *это* - `$(".btn btn-warning")` - не работало.